# Set "topic" of multiple patches simultaneously in gerrit

Tags: gerrit

Is there a simpler way to set topic for multiple patches(around 70 patches all under 1 branch) in gerrit (Ideally in 1 -go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push all these changes again to the `refs/for/<branch>` branch. There you can use the `%topic=<topic>` suffix; e.g. `refs/for/master%topic=my-topic`.

See: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#push_create

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST API to [set the topic](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#set-topic) for existing changes.

Comment: This way only works for one change per command. You cannot set a topic for all changes in one go.

Comment: But you can easily wrap it in a loop over all changes you'd like to change the topic for.